# async await inside setTimeout inside forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I need to scedule some background jobs in nodejs, so I need a job to run after the previous have finished.

Inside a function I have the code below.

```
jobArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await collectChannelsData(item)
  }, i * 10000);
});
console.log('go to 2nd job')

jobArray.forEach((item, i) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await collectVideosData(item)
  }, i * 10000);
});
console.log('finish')
```

The problem is, because setTimeout is an async function, forEach doesnt wait for it to finish, and go on in the second job. Is there any possible solution for it?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: One possible solution would be to transform my code into :

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

for (const job of jobArray) {
  await collectChannelsData(job) 
  await wait(10000);
}
for (const job of jobArray) {
  await collectVideosData(job) 
  await wait(10000);
}
```

But i am looking for a approach which includes, setTimeout and forEach.

Comment: BEFORE you added the "one possible solution", I wrote an answer that shows that option.  That is your best option.

Comment: I know, i write it exactly the same time with you :). I know its the best solution, I am just wondering if its possible to make it with setTimeout and forEach. BTW thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: No.  `.forEach()` pays no attention to what its callback returns so it just blindly runs all the loops of the iteration without ever waiting for any  async operations to finish.  As such, there is no way to make it do what you are trying to do.  In addition, the `for` loop with `await` looks simpler too and you can know when everything is done.  It's just a better option.

Comment: _But i am looking for a better approach_ Better in what way? That does exactly what you want it to, as well as being both readable and efficient. Unless you want both loops to run simultaneously?

Comment: Wrong words. I needed a better approach with forEach and setTimeout, but as @jfriend00 told me, its not possible to use them.

Comment: You should explain why you want a `forEach` instead of a `for of`, otherwise, you should just use the `for of`

Comment: Really ? Because something works its forbidden to look for other solutions too ? :P BTW thank you for your time and for your answer

Comment: @NikosChatzivasileiadis It's not forbidden, it's just a lot more messy.

Comment: @NikosChatzivasileiadis Because SO is about solving problems. Your problem is solved unless you explain why you can't use a `forEach`

Comment: I was just trying a couple of hours to achieve it with forEach and I was just curious to find out if it was possible! But guys I really appreciate your time and thank you for your help! @3limin4t0r

Comment: and @JuanMendes

Answer (score 1):

Note: This question originally asked ***"I am looking for a better approach"*** and it originally did not contain the example using `await wait(10000)`.  I wrote this answer to that original question (before it was edited).  The question has since been edited into a bit of a different question.

> But i am looking for a approach which includes, setTimeout and forEach.

There is no clean way to do this with `.forEach()` without involving variables outside the loop and probably chaining promises.  `.forEach()` is not promise-aware in any way so it is generally best to abandon using it when you want to sequence asynchronous iterations of the loop.

Using a `for` loop with `await` is one of the better options for this type of problem.  It is meets the main objective of sequencing your asynchronous operations with a specific delay between the completion of one asynchronous operation and the start of the next.  It is simple, readable, efficient, easy to maintain, it provides the caller a means to know when everything is done and it returns asynchronous errors back to the caller.  Your `.forEach()` loop does not meet your objectives or do many of these other things.

You can make the timer into a promise-returning function that you can use `await` with:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

async function run() {

    for (let item of jobArray) {
        await collectChannelsData(item)
        await delay(10000);
    }
    // go to second job now that first job is finished
    for (let item of jobArray) {
        await collectVideosData(item);
        await delay(10000);
    }
}

run().then(() => {
   console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

As it appears you may already know, `.forEach()` does not pay any attention to what the callback you pass it returns so it's completely non-promise-aware and thus really doesn't have any place when using promises any more.  A regular `for` loop is so much more useful because it will suspend the loop when using `await`.

---

There are ways to hack things with `.forEach()` using a higher scoped promise that is declared external to the loop, but those options are not clean at all so I won't bother showing them here.

---

Before we had `await`, we used to use `.reduce()` to sequence promises.  This creates a chain of promises that call their functions sequentially:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

// use .reduce() to chain promises so async operations are sequenced
jobArray.reduce(p, item => {
    return p.then(() => {
         return collectChannelsData(item).then(() => delay(10000));
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(() => {
    jobArray.reduce(p, item => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return collectVideosData(item).then(() => delay(10000));
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}).then(() => {
   console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

But hopefully you can see how much cleaner the `await` implementation appears as all the `.reduce()` scaffolding gets in the way of seeing the control flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a `forEach` approach, you have to write your own async version of `forEach`

```js
(async function() {

  const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  async function forEach(arr, cb) {
    for (const item of arr) {
      await cb(item);
    }
  }

  await forEach([1, 2, 3], async function(item) {
    await wait(500);
    console.log("Step" + item);
  });

  console.log("Done");


})()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you explicitly want to use `forEach` since it's not very pretty. But it is absolutely possible to use a `forEach`.

```
let queue = Promise.resolve();

jobArray.forEach(job => {
  queue = queue.then(() => collectChannelsData(job));
});

jobArray.forEach(job => {
  queue = queue.then(() => collectVideosData(job));
});

queue.then(() => console.log("finish"));
// or if you are inside an async function
await queue;
console.log("finish");
```

If for some reason still want to add delays (`setTimeout`) in there even though the promises wait on each other. You can do so by changing the loops to something like this:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

jobArray.forEach((job, i) => {
  queue = queue.then(() => collectChannelsData(job))
               .then(() => wait(10000 * i));
});
```

I would personally go the cleaner for-loop with `await` as [answered by jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956297/3982562).

---

You can make the above cleaner by defining a helper class like `Queue`, which would do a lot of the duplicated code `queue = queue.then(...)`.

```
class Queue {
  constructor(initial) {
    this.promise = Promise.resolve(initial);
  }

  then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    return this.promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
  }

  add(task) {
    this.promise = this.then(task);
  }
}

const queue = new Queue();
jobArray.forEach(job => queue.add(() => collectChannelsData(job)));
jobArray.forEach(job => queue.add(() => collectVideosData(job)));

await queue; // <- assuming you are in async function context
console.log("finish");
```

Comment: Sure, you can HACK something with `.forEach()` using variables that are external to the loop.  That is not really the point here.  Also, this doesn't insert the delay between completion of one and start of the next that is part of the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 It depends what you call a hack. `forEach` is only used to mutate state and has no other purpose, so I wouldn't call it a hack.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The problem in the question is the the next job starts before the previous one finishes. This answer does solve the problem.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes, I see what you're doing now.